# Como recorrer el mismo objeto array n cantidad de veces

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript

Necesito recorrer el mismo objecto e imprimirlo, según la n cantidad de comidas, que tenga el usuario. Tengo los siguientes arrays

```
[id, nombre, Arroz con pollo, Tortillas azadas, Pollo guisado],
[id, nombre, Arepas , Torillas, ''],
[id, nombre, Fideos, '', '']
```

en la base de datos debería ser algo como esto:

```
1 | Saul | Arroz con pollo | Comida1
2 | Saul | Tortillas azadas| Comida2
3 | Saul | Pollo guisado   | Comida3
4 | Pablo | Arepas         | Comida1
5 | Pablo | Torillas       | Comida2
6 | Raul  | Fideos         | Comida1
```

Porque los registros van en base a la cantidad de comida por usaurio, pero con el codigo que tengo me traigo la primera comida de cada objeto, estaba viendo, que hay ejemplos con linkedlist y .push, pero bueno si se tiene que usar otro for, lo hago, pero si me podrían mostrar mas o menos como seria por favor cn el codigo que tengo o si hay otra implmentación y muy agradecido con sus comentarios.

Mi codigo

```
ConditionData(lines, values: Array<any>){
while (lines !== null) {
    const info: FoodDto = {food: '', name: '', id:0, noFood:''}
    if (values.length >= 4 && values[4] !== '' && values[4] !== null) {
        console.log("entre aqui1", values[3])
        const id = parseInt(service + "1");
        info.name = values[1]
        info.food = values[2]
        info.noFood = 'food1'
        info.id = id

        return info
    }

    if (values.length >= 5 && values[5] !== '' && values[5] !== null) {
        console.log("entre aqui2", values[3])
        const id = parseInt(service + "1");
        info.name = values[1]
        info.food = values[2]
        info.nofood = 'food2'
        info.id = id

        return info
    }

    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de resolver esto puede ser de esta manera:

```js
let datos = [
  [1, "Leo", "comida1", "comida2", "comida3"],
  [2, "Jorge", "comida1", "comida2", ''],
  [3, "Juan", "comida1", '', '']
]



let datosAcomodados = datos.reduce((a, b) => {
  //Obtenemos los valores generales para organizarlos
  let id = b[0]
  let nombre = b[1]
  let comidas = b.splice(2, 4)

  //Si el objeto para organizar no contiene la clave, creamos
  //uno y lo inicializamos. Esto nos sirve para sumar duplicados
  if (!a.hasOwnProperty(id)) a[id] = {
    nombre: "",
    comidas: []
  }
  //Una vez que existe asignamos los datos
  a[id].nombre = nombre
  //Con filter quitamos las comidas vacias, los tres puntos nos permiten 
  // pasar todos los datos del arreglo filtrado a comidas. Si se repitio
  // el id, aqui sumamos las comidas.
  a[id].comidas.push(...comidas.filter(x => x !== ""))
  
  return a
}, {})


console.log(datosAcomodados)

// Con los datos ordenados de esa manera ahora si, podemos imprimir:
//Obtenemos las llaves en un arreglo y hacemos forEach.
Object.keys(datosAcomodados).forEach(key => {
  //Obtenemos el objeto de cada id unico
  let objeto = datosAcomodados[key]
  //Recorremos las comidas
  objeto.comidas.forEach(comida => console.log(objeto.nombre, comida))
})
```

Comment: oye muchisimas gracias, pero si le tengo que agregar una propiedad, que no esta en el array por ejemplo "Comida1", "Comida2" y "Comida3", el max es 3, como le agregarias esa propiedad??

Comment: No te entiendo. Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar un ejemplo de lo que me comentas? Para editar mi respuesta

Comment: editada, hay una propiedad, que no viene en el array, sino que se la pongo afuera, como lo son "Comida1", "Comida2" y "Comida3", como le agregarías esa propiedad string, sino viene dentro del array? Sino que dependiendo de la cantidad de comidas del usuario, se las va reyenando??